# How to create a ASP.NET Core Project in VB.NET language using dotnet cli command?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-new

I have migrated the project from Dot.Net-Framework 4.7.2 to Asp.Net-Core 3.1 with VB.NET language. I have checked in Microsoft link below, there is no CLI Command for VB.NET in Asp.Net Core templates. They mentioned only C# language for ASP.NET Core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

[image]

Kindly let me know if there is any way to create a **ASP.NET Core** Project in **"VB.NET"**

Comment: `dotnet new webapp --help`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, asp.net core couldn't create the MVC vb.net project.  You could  use `dotnet new --list` to see the result:

[image]

Besides, according to this github issue, ASP.NET Core Doesn't provide a razor syntax that supports VB.NET.

The workaround is using the custom library like Vazor and ZML to design MVC views and Razor Pages.

More details, you could refer to this github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20633).

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/ Then what about the link ?

Comment: This is the support planned for .NET 5.0, something like road map. The VB.NET still don't support web api and MVC now.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit older, to be sure, but the good news is that today there IS a way to build ASP.NET Core applications in VB.NET.

For the past few days I've been working with Vazor, found [here](https://github.com/VBAndCs/Vazor) and [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ModernVBNET.Vazor). I've found it to be remarkable. It's a very clever solution to a long-standing problem.

The author also has plans to enable Blazor apps in VB.NET projects.